# organize javascript,php code for easy to read way when have nested functions

Tags: javascript, php, oop

this is my sample code...

```
one();


function one()
{
    function abc()
    {
      //code 
    }


    function bcd()
    {
      //code 
    }

    abc();
    bcd();
}
```

this is regarding php,javascript.i want to structure this code easy readable manner with or without using object oriented programming techniques.

how to call function abc from outside function one..?

Comment: Usually, you wouldn't define a function in a scope narrower than the scope you want to use it in.

Comment: use classes or namespaces for do this.

Comment: on javascript I recommend not nest many anonymous functions. if you go to nest functions is better to give some name because it is easier to see the stack and debug

Comment: @rkmax — There aren't any anonymous functions involved.

Comment: The following answer may be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways:

```
// when using one() as a constructor for an object
function one()
{
    this.abc = function() { };
    this.def = function() { };
}
obj = new one();
obj.abc();


// prototype
function one()
{

}
one.prototype.abc = function() { };
one.prototype.def = function() { };
obj = new one();
obj.abc();


// module pattern
function one()
{
    var abc = function () { };
    var def = function () { };
    return {
        abc: abc,
        def: def
    }
}
obj = one();
obj.abc();


// or just assign it as a property to your function
function one()
{

}
one.abc = function() { }
one.def = function() { }
one.abc();
```

pick whatever suits you.

Answer (score 1):

The nested functions in your example is scoped within the function and are thrown away after the function one() completes; so they are not exposed.

One could use closure to expose the function ... [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) ... http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-closures-demystified/ ... but the easiest way given your simple example is to use the abc namespace created by the function.

```
function abc() {
   abc.def = function () {alert("hello")}
}
abc(); // add def function to abc namespace.
abc.def(); // call def function which is part of the abc object.
```

To avoid object notation, one could pass a variable to the function.

```
function abc(operator) {
   function def() {alert("hello")}

   if (operator == def) {def()}
}
abc("def");
```

However this becomes more difficult to read than using object notation, because i need to look at the function to determine what is happening where abc.def() tells me I'm calling def() which is part of abc. And it causes a performance hit because def needs to be recreated on each call.